Ngrok webhooks not getting verified in Meta webhook's callbackurl
I have been using ngrok for local testing for quite some time now with no problem at all. But recently, when I set my webhook in my app's callback url, it says:

The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later.

The url and token is correct, the endpoint does not get hit when I am doing it from Meta. When I use postman to make a GET request to that same url, I can see the request on ngrok terminal and the vscode terminal too. But not when I am verifying it on Meta. Is Meta now allowing requests to ngrok? What can I do to avoid this?

To clarify: you're not seeing the challenge request come in at all?

Yes! Nothing from Meta. But postman worked fine.

Looks like a old ngrok issue. Basically, META is setting Ngrok as an unsafe endpoint (I was using ngrok before block for local tests). You can use another local tunneling service, this one works to me. Good Ngrok Alternative
You can easily run without install anything using this (Using port 8000 as example):
ssh -R 80:localhost:8000 serveo.net


Yes, seems like it. Now I have switched to zrok for local testing.

This worked for me while having trouble to use vscode tunnels to test the instagram api
